# Realloc Memory Intercept

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I want to read several files and add lines of text to the content. I would like to save the new changed content in a buffer. The files can be from 0 bytes to 16 MB in size. By adding the lines of text, the file can also be much larger, depending on the content.

At the beginning, I reserve 512 bytes of memory with calloc.

```
wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t*)calloc(512, sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Whenever adding text to memory, I check if the size of the reserved memory is still sufficient with the function realloc. This works quite reliably for small files only with larger files the program crashes. Debbug is unfortunately not possible because of the constellation.

Now my question.
If I extend the memory repeatedly with realloc but it fails, is the if statement with buffer == NULL correct? The buffer can theoretically not be zero, since it was already filled before.

How can I catch the error cleanly or fix it?

```
size_t memoryallocated = 512;

wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t*)calloc(memoryallocated , sizeof(wchar_t));          
while (memoryuse + contenlength >= memoryallocated)
{
 memoryallocated *= 2;
 buffer = (wchar_t *)realloc(buffer, memoryallocated* sizeof(wchar_t));     
 if ((buffer == NULL))
 {
   return NULL;
 }
}

wmemcpy(buffer + memoryuse, contentbuf,contenlength);
memoryuse += contenlength;    // thx @pm100

return buffer;
```

Comment: *Debbug is unfortunately not possible because of the constellation* -- what?

Comment: i think you mean `memoryused += contenlength`

Comment: I am working with an API and need to open the files in the program, there is no debugging possible.

Comment: Crashes how? It sounds like you might be having overcommit issues. You could catch the signal and print its details ...

Comment: @o11c 
That's the problem of the API and the program. I can not catch the error anywhere and see the job. Sometimes I get the following message in the error log.
(page protection fault) is at offset 1: 00001F70 [sys]

Comment: Then it sounds like you either need to complain to the server admins that you can't perform basic tasks, or at *least* provide a lot of details about the environment.

Comment: the latter is the case, but this is not so easy, thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm), you can see that function returns `NULL` if it cannot resize your buffer (due to lack of memory or any other reason). It does not return the old pointer.

So comparing the returned value with `NULL` is absolutely correct.

Aside from that you should never do

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, ...);
```

Because if `realloc` returns `NULL` you have lost the old pointer which was not freed (`realloc` does not free if it cannot reallocate). This will result in a memory leak.

You should always do -

```
void * new_ptr = realloc(buffer, new_size); // new_size > 0 

if (new_ptr == NULL) {
    // Handle error and keep using buffer
} else {
    buffer = new_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I accepted and implemented your advice.
My question is answered even if my problem persists. But the mistake is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Note: `new_ptr == NULL` is not a  certain out-of-memory a condition if amount of memory allocated is zero.

Comment: @chux I didn't get you. Do you mean more checks are required than `new_ptr == NULL` or that `NULL` return doesn't always mean error?

Comment: "If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. If the size of
the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."  §7.23 1

Comment: @chux very well. I will make add necessary comments to the sample to show the assumption.